# How to write resolvers for GraphQL Mutation fields

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

My GraphQL schema looks like this:

```
type Outer {
   id: ID
   name: String,
   inner: [Inner]
}

type Inner {
   id: ID
   name: String
}

input OuterInput {
   name: String,
   inner: InnerInput
}

Input InnerInput {
   name: String
}

type Query {
   getOuter(id: ID): Outer
}

type Mutation {
   createOuter(outer: OuterInput): Outer
}
```

In database, Outer object is store this way:

```
{
   id: 1,
   name: ‘test’,
   inner: [5, 6] //IDs of inner objects. Not the entire inner object
}
```

Outer and Inner are stored in separate database collections/tables (I’m using DynamoDB)

My resolvers look like this:

```
Query: {
   getOuter: (id) => {
      //return ‘Outer’ object with the ‘inner’ IDs from the database since its stored that way
   }
}


Outer: {
   inner: (outer) => {
      //return ‘Inner’ objects with ids from ‘outer.inner’ is returned
   }
}

Mutation: {
   createOuter: (outer) => {
      //extract out the IDs out of the ‘inner’ field in ‘outer’ and store in DB.
   }
}

OuterInput: {
   inner: (outer) => {
      //Take the full ‘Inner’ objects from ‘outer’ and store in DB.
     // This is the cause of the error
   }
}
```

But I’m not able to write a resolver for the ‘inner’ field in ‘OuterInput’ similar to what I did for ‘Outer’. GraphQL throws an error saying

```
Error: OuterInput was defined in resolvers, but it's not an object
```

How can I handle such a scenario if writing resolvers for Input types are not allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvers are not necessary for input types. Input types are only passed in as values to field arguments, which means their value is already know -- it does not need to be resolved by the server, unlike values for fields being returned in the query.

The signature for every resolver is the same and includes 4 parameters: 1) the parent object, 2) the arguments for the field being resolved, 3) the context and 4) an object containing more detailed information about the request as a whole.

So to access the `outer` argument for your `createOuter` mutation:

```
Mutation: {
   createOuter: (root, args, ctx, info) => {
      console.log('Outer: ', args.outer)
      console.log('Outer name: ', args.outer.name)
      console.log('Inner: ', args.outer.inner)
      console.log('Inner name: ', args.outer.inner.name)
      // resolver logic here
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I apologize for not giving more information as to what I'm trying to achieve in my question. In the Query section, The fetching of 'Outer' and 'Inner' are in separate resolvers. getOuter will fetch only the 'Outer' object from the DB and if in case the query is something like

getOuter(id: 1) {
  name
  inner
}

then to fetch the 'Inner' object, graphql will call the Outer.inner resolver.
I'm looking for similar kind of separation in Mutations also.
If 'Outer' object without 'inner' is given, createOuter is called. If 'inner' in 'Outer' is present, one more resolver is called.

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, there's no conventional way to do that. Again, resolvers are used to resolve the value of fields, not inputs. GraphQL only type-checks the inputs -- it doesn't walk through all the nodes like it does for field values, because the values are known already and there's nothing to resolve. If you have some kind of logic around "if foo is given, do this; if bar is given, do this", that logic will need to be contained inside of your mutation's resolver.

Comment: At best, you can maybe extract out some kind of helper function that will walk through the given arguments and figure out what actions need to be taken based on the structure of the arguments object. That function could then be reused across your resolvers.

Comment: Yea that sounds like a good idea. Will create a separate helper layer for delegating the execution for nested input types.